# Difference between Update and Import in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I followed all the steps mentioned in the official blog post here:

[Remediate drift via resource import with AWS CloudFormation | AWS Management & Governance Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/remediate-drift-via-resource-import-with-aws-cloudformation/)

Instead of using "import resource" at step 4, if I use "update" button, I get the same results.

> 4. Select our stack and Import resource into stack, from the Stack actions menu.

What is the difference between Update and Import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** is normally used to tell CloudFormation that the template has changed. This can result in new resources being created, modified or deleted.

CloudFormation is not aware of any changes made outside of itself, so it is preferable to always change resources through CloudFormation so that it remains in-sync with the resource configuration.

That article seems to pushing the idea that, if something has changed outside of CloudFormation, it is best to "forget" about the resource, then **Import** it into the stack. An Import adds an existing resource to the stack without CloudFormation attempting to create it.

I guess Updating the DynamoDB table works because only the `BILLING_MODE` has changed.  It is possible that CloudFormation can become confused when it tries to make a change that has already been made. For example, if a subnet needs to change AZs, it will need to delete and recreate the subnet. This would lead to resources with different IDs. In such a case, the recommended process of Forget + Import would need to be used.

**Bottom line:** The article is showing the general process, but in some situations, and Update might suffice.